# How to figure out the width and height of a written bitmap font string

Tags: java, bitmap, libgdx

Okay, so I have this.

```
calibri.draw(FBLA_Game.spriteBatch, "Rooftop Defender",0 ,0 );
```

Anyways, this code... I need the text to be centered. Instead of the 0's, I would have it like this:

```
calibri.draw(FBLA_Game.spriteBatch, "Rooftop Defender",Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 ,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 );
```

But this isn't what I want. this centers the beginning of where it writes the words.  So then for the width I would need to subtract the width of the word being written, But I cannot figure out how to get the width of "Rooftop Defender" that is being written.

Thanks for any and all help,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new versions (*>1.6*) of LibGDX **BitmapFont** is being handled with [GlyphLayout](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.html) class which you can use to calculate the future width of your rendered string

```
    //out of render() method! this call is expensive
    GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout(calibri, "Rooftop Defender");

    ...

    //render()
    float glyphLayoutWidth = glyphLayout.width;
```

Comment: Yup **create()** is good place - you can also place it outside any methods in class body.  To know what Glyph Layout is just [take a look at this nice Badlogic blog article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658) and learn more.

Comment: Okay, but what is the layout.width thing???? It's pulling up an error.   

(PS. Thank you, a lot!!!)

Comment: layout cannot be resovled to a variable

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake in a code - check out updated version

Comment: This worked, thanks. Had to make it static. moved the float into the create() method, makes it not have to reload the object( float) every single time it loads, to slow it down. Is that alright??? Anyways, thanks. It helped.

Comment: Creating new instances of **object** is quite expensive but since float is primitive (not an object) it should not affect your performance I guess